# Jsoup how to find order of text in siblings?

Tags: jsoup

I want the result as apple:1, orange:2, pear:3. Dots (...) represents other tags the number and names of which are unknown but similar across 3 columns. Could anyone help? Thanks.

```
    <tr>
    <td> 
      <span>
         .....
          <h>apple</h>
         .....
      </span>  
     </td>
     <td> 
       <span>
             .....
              <h>orange</h>
             .....
          </span>
        </td>
        <td> 
          <span>
             .....
              <h>pear</h>
             .....
          </span>
        </td>
   </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `getElementsByTag()` in any element to get all its descendant elements of a given type (`element.getElementsByTag("h")` will get all `<h>`), and then you can iterate over the result with a simple for to get the order.

See sample code:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
import org.jsoup.select.*;
public class JsoupHtmlSiblingsOrder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String html = "<html><body><span>HELLO!</span><table id=\"myTable\"><tbody>        " +
                "<tr><td> <span>                                                           " +
                "         .....                                                            " +
                "         <h>apple</h>                                                     " +
                "         .....                                                            " +
                "         </span>                                                          " +
                "</td><td><span>                                                           " +
                "         .....                                                            " +
                "         <h>orange</h>                                                    " +
                "         .....                                                            " +
                "         </span>                                                          " +
                "</td><td><span>                                                           " +
                "         .....                                                            " +
                "         <h>pear</h>                                                      " +
                "         .....                                                            " +
                "         </span>                                                          " +
                "</td></tr>                                                                " +
                "</tbody></table></body></html>                                            ";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Element table = doc.getElementById("myTable");;
        Elements hs = table.getElementsByTag("h");
        for (int i = 0; i < hs.size(); i++) {
            Element h = hs.get(i);
            System.out.println(h.text()+":"+(i+1));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
apple:1
orange:2
pear:3
```

Comment: That's what I am looking for. Thank you. I try to vote up for you but get declined (reputation<15).

Comment: Is there a simple way to achieve similar result if <h> tag is also unknown, i.e, the tag surrounding the text is not fixed but it can be any of the tags (h, span, div, etc.)? Thanks.

Comment: Hey there, I just came by and saw this comment of yours now... Do you still need it?

Comment: Sorry for the late response as I've been away. Sure, please show me what you got. Thanks.